# Node.js Puppeteer clicking on the expand arrow

Tags: javascript, node.js, click, puppeteer

I am trying to click on the expand icon for "My Team".

Element:

```
<div id="pt1:_UISnvr:0:nvgpgl2_groupNode_manager_resources" title="My Team" class="navmenu-header x1a"><div><span class="x3im">My Team</span></div><div><a id="pt1:_UISnvr:0:nvgcil_groupNode_manager_resources".....
```

Selector: #pt1\:_UISnvr\:0\:nvgpgl2_groupNode_manager_resources 
JS Path: document.querySelector("#pt1\\:_UISnvr\\:0\\:nvgpgl2_groupNode_manager_resources") 
Xpath: //*[@id="pt1:_UISnvr:0:nvgpgl2_groupNode_manager_resources"]

I have tried a few variations of the above including just the ID, however I am not having any luck.  What is the proper format for `page.click`?

```
await page.click('#pt1\\\:_UISnvr\\\:0\\\:nvgpgl2_groupNode_manager_resources');
```

[image: Expand arrow]

```html
    <div id="pt1:_UISnvr:0:nvgpgl2_groupNode_manager_resources" title="My Team" class="navmenu-header x1a"><div><span class="x3im">My Team</span></div><div><a id="pt1:_UISnvr:0:nvgcil_groupNode_manager_resources" title="Expand My Team" class="svg-func svg-highlight size12 xkm" style="padding-top: 2.5px; width: 20.58px; transform: rotate(0deg); padding-bottom: 0px;" onclick="this.focus();return false;" href="#"><svg id="pt1:_UISnvr:0:nvgcil_groupNode_manager_resources::icon" class="xi6" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="16" height="16" viewBox="0 0 16 16"><g><path class="svg-icon03" d="M13.083,7L11.973,5.98,7.988,9.965,4.027,5.98l-1.078.985L7.973,12.02l0.043-.039L8.058,12.02Z"></path></g></svg><span class="xmo"> </span></a></div></div>
```

Comment: Could you post the markup (html) of the image you added

Answer (score 1):

It seems these should be both valid selectors (maybe you need to wait for them a bit):

```js
await page.click('div#pt1\\:_UISnvr\\:0\\:nvgpgl2_groupNode_manager_resources');
```

```js
await page.click('div[id="#pt1:_UISnvr:0:nvgpgl2_groupNode_manager_resources"]');
```

Sometimes these variants can help when the previous ones fail:

```js
await page.evaluate(() => { document.querySelector('div#pt1\\:_UISnvr\\:0\\:nvgpgl2_groupNode_manager_resources').click(); });
```

```js
await page.evaluate(() => { document.querySelector('div[id="#pt1:_UISnvr:0:nvgpgl2_groupNode_manager_resources"]').click(); });
```